# Restore-SPSite : The backup file should be restored to a server with version '14.0.0.7106' or later

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Facing issue while restoring the SharePoint site to the staging environment.
I am getting below issue white restoring site:

```
Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with version '14.0.0.7106' or later.
```

Though I have the same version of SharePoint installed in the production environment as well as in staging environment.

> Both servers have Microsoft SharePoint server 2010 (14.0.7015.1000)
>   And Service pack 2 for Microsoft SharePoint server 2010 (KB2687453) 64-bit edition.

*The only difference that both are using different SQL servers (those servers are also identical)*

Still, I am facing issue while restore, does anybody have the idea how to fix this?

I also tried `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content` command but it gives below message:

```
WARNING: Database [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] does not need to be
upgraded.
```

I can attach the database but we are using Managed metadata service and I don't want to lose its connection with the earlier list items.

Comment: sometimes a patch is installed and the wizzard is not executed, then SharePoint do not detect the lastest version. The only way to check this is running the wizard :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both farms have same SharePoint version by running the following command in SharePoint power shell : (get-spfarm).buildversion

If the build version in the destination farm is not as expected , then you have to run the configuration wizard on the destination farm to make sure the update is properly installed .

Comment: In my case versions are different on both the machines. production is running with 14.0.7106.5002 and Staging have 14.0.7015.1000, to matchup both, I have downloaded the patch for prod version from-http://sp2013galaxy.blogspot.ae/2014/05/sharepoint-server-2010-patch-updates.html
Microsoft URL:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2825949/description-of-the-sharepoint-server-2010-cumulative-update-package-sh
after patch gets installed then I performed a successful restoration.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to double check your destination farm patch level.

You can also look into upgrade and migration section in central admin if the databases are in compatibility range. If it does, then you might have to upgrade those using SharePoint config wizard or powershell

Answer (score 0):

Verify the dbo.versions table and the content database version.

Start with the Windows Control Panel / Programs and Features which will list all the fixes installed on the box and on top the "Manage Patch Status" page in the Central admin to verify the patch status on the different servers.

Re-backup the site and try to restore it again to see if the backup file is corrupt.

Try using Stsadm commands to backup and restore, compare the results.

```
stsadm –o backup –url <URL of the site collection> -filename <Name of the backup file> 
stsadm –o restore –url <URL of the site collection> -filename <Name of the backup file>
```

A similar case:
https://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/your-backup-is-from-a-different-version-of-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation/